# MS Access Form where user name is selected from list

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, prompt

I am going to rephrase a previous question that I had posted:

I have built a form in access that allows users to enter in their hours worked by activity (i.e. transactional processing, project time, vacation etc.). The fields on the form are:

1) user name
2) start date
3) end date
4) activity 
5) hours spent

Is there a way to have this form in such a way that when it is opened up by a user, a prompt automatically appears that forces you to select the user name from a list of users? Than once the user name is selected, all records entered through this form have the user name field already populated (unless the form is closed and reopened again)?

Based on the user name selection in the prompt, the toggling of records using the "Previous Record" and "Next Record" arrows should strictly pertain to the selected user name selected.

** this is my current form**

[image]

**steps used to produce the solution mentioned below**

1) delete the combo box called "User Name"
2) add an unbound hidden text box and call it txUN
3) add the VBA code loaded below but changed the txtusername reference to user_full_name as this is the name of the column in the table that should store these records
4) created the form below with a combo box for user names and called it cbousername
5) change the frm_sample reference to [Specialist - Timesheet Entry]

Comment: Could you not automatically grab a username using Environ$("Username")? Or do you want users to be able to select other users profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION, Open User Name form first:**

Create a form like the below with a hidden textbox named `txtUN`.:

[image]

With the following code behind:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUN & "") = 0 Then DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_UserName", acNormal, , , , acDialog
  If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUsername & "") = 0 Then txtUsername = txtUN
End Sub
```

Then create a form like below.  Name the drop down `cboUserName`.

[image]

With the following code behind:

```
Private Sub cboUserName_AfterUpdate()
   Forms!frm_Sample.txtUN = cboUserName
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  If (VBA.Strings.Len(cboUserName & "") = 0) Then
     MsgBox "You must supply a user name before proceeding.", , "ERROR: Missing Info."
     Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```

When you open `frm_Sample` it will check to see if `txtUN` has a value.  If not it will open `frm_UserName` as a dialog.  The user must select a user name and close the form.  When navigating to another record if `txtUsername` is empty then it is assigned whatever `txtUN` contains.

Comment: i have been trying this and am receiving a run time '440' error. "you cant assign a value to this object." If i click debug than this line of code is highlighted: `Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].txtUN = cbousername`

Comment: Is `txtUN` a hidden text box that is unbound?

Comment: im not sure. how do you make this a hidden box? and what is `txtUsername` referring to?

Comment: In design view of the form if you set the `Visible` property to `No` for the `txtUN` text box it will be hidden in normal view.  It is used just to store the user name.  `txtUsername` is the actual text box that is bound to a field in your table where you want to store the user name.

Comment: `txtUN` is just used to store the username on the form only, it does not affect the database at all.  When you move between records the form checks to see if `txtUsername` has a value and if not it assigns it what `txtUN` contains.  Since `txtUN` is not bound to any field it will maintain the same value even when moving between records.

Comment: once the window pops up to select the user name from the drop down, it will not make the selection and access gives that error sound. If i close the window to that pop up than i get a Run Time 2447 that there is an invalid . (dot) or ! operator or invalid parenthesis. If i click debug, its complaining about this code: `If VBA.Strings.Len(txtusername & "") = 0 Then`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58276/discussion-between-linger-and-jt2013).

Comment: do you have an idea how to close the pop up for (frm_username) once the user selects their name? Adding `DoCmd.Close` to the `Private Sub cboUserName_AfterUpdate()` event produces a run time 2585: This action cant be carried out while processing a form or report event. Once i click debug, the `DoCmd.Close` is highlighted yellow.

Answer (score -1):

You can automatically pass the actual windows username to your form and with a table lookup gain your application related username.

Probably you already have a table (lets say table `tblUsers` with a field that contains your username, for example `fldUsername`) in your database that stores all valid usernames. Just add a column to this table (named `fldDomainUser`) that contains the domain AND/OR  the username of the logged-in user.

```
Environ$("userdomain") + "\" + Environ$("username")
```

will return a string with your domain, a '\' and your actual username.

The function

```
dlookup ("[fldUsername]","[tblUsers]","[fldDomainUser]='"+cstr(Environ$("userdomain") + "\" + Environ$("username"))+"'")
```

will return the username.

Set your actual username in the form's `before_insert` event

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
   [ctrlUsername] = Environ$("userdomain") + "\" + Environ$("username")
End Sub
```

so that all new created records automatically contain your username.

Do not forget to filter your form or its `Recordsource` accordingly .