# MS Access form - New record on open and after saving record

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, record

In relation to my question posted here:

[MS Access Form where user name is selected from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003154/ms-access-form-where-user-name-is-selected-from-list)

I have created a form used as an employee time sheet. Users double click this form and another form pops up where they select their user name from a combo box and the main time sheet form loads up specifically for their user name. They are able to add new records, and also view their previous submissions by scrolling through the "Previous" and "Next" records.

However, when a user opens up the form, their last record displays. Also, when a new record is saved, that new record continues to display unless a user clicks the "New (blank) record" button.

Can someone help me modify the VBA code in the form to allow for:
1) A blank record to automatically load when the form is opened up
2) A blank record to automatically load when a new record is saved/modified.

This is the pop up window - form that pops up when you select the main data entry form:

[image]

This is the code behind the pop up form (above):

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUN & "") = 0 Then DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_UserName", acNormal, , , , acDialog
If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUsername & "") = 0 Then txtUsername = txtUN
End Sub

 Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


   Dim ctl As Control

   On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate


   If Me.Dirty Then

      If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
      End If
   End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate

End Sub
```

This is the main data entry form [Specialist - Timesheet Entry]:

[image]

This is the code behind the [Specialist - Timesheet Entry] form:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cboUserName_AfterUpdate()
   Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].txtUN = cbousername
   Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].Filter = "user_full_name = '" & cbousername & "'"
   Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].FilterOn = True
      'Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].Requery
      'DoCmd.Close

End Sub
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  If (VBA.Strings.Len(cbousername & "") = 0) Then
     MsgBox "You must supply a user name before proceeding.", , "ERROR: Missing Info."
     Cancel = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Once the [Specialist - Timesheet Entry] is selected, the [form_UserName] pops up. You must select a user name from the list, and hit the "X" button. Once the "X" button is selected than the data entry form [Specialist - Timesheet Entry] will appear for a user to enter the necessary fields. **I am also looking for the user to not have to hit the "X" button in order to initiate the [Specialist - Timesheet Entry] form. Ideally once the user selects the user name from the drop down list in the pop up, i'd like the form to close automatically and generate the [Specialist - Timesheet Entry] form.**

Comment: Try `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` for new records. Put this `On Load` and if the user wants to save the record, you need to handle the `Yes` portion by try putting that code in there, also. I'm iffy about the Me.Dirty code.

Comment: @overmind if i add the suggested code i get a run time error 2424. "The expression you entered has a field, control or property name that MS Access cant find." If i click debug, this code is highlighted in red `If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUsername & "") = 0 Then`

Comment: i have also tried this code: `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew` and its the same issue.

Comment: @overmind the code you provided above is the same code you gave me in another question i had asked but for some reason this situation is throwing a run time.

Comment: Try to debug it. `If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUsername & "") = 0 Then MsgBox("An erorr was caught") End If`

Comment: @overmind for a novice VBA user, that doesn't really help. Please explain.

Comment: We are testing if your line of code `If VBA.Strings.Len(txtUsername & "") = 0 Then` is causing the error or if there's something else. If the length of txtUsername is 0, then the MsgBox will show up. You wrote the code, you should at least understand that.

Comment: @overmind the message box does not show up.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure where you are putting the code I suggested to you. Can you update your question to reflect your current state?

Comment: Can you give details of which Form is what? Which form is the Popup form, where is the User info collected?

Comment: @PaulFrancis please see the details that i've added to the question. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I think I have something for you here.

I share the same sentiment as OverMind - I'm iffy about the Me.Dirty code. I don't think it's necessary. All you need to do is click the dropdown, select a name and open a form that is filtered using the selected name. Same thing goes for the Form_BeforeUpdate event. You're not actually modifying any data, you're just clicking and selecting. I recommend removing both of those events.

If you don't mind, I reworked this a little since I don't have the entire application in front of me. Try the following (there's a few parts):

**1.) frm_UserName**

Comment your existing code in the `cboUserName_AfterUpdate` event and add this line:

```
       DoCmd.OpenForm "Specialist - Timesheet Entry"
        'Open the main timesheet form and set the filter based on the dropdown selection in the previous form.
       Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].Filter = "Username = '" & Forms![frm_UserName].cboUserName.Column(1) & "'"
       'Turn the filter on.
       Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].FilterOn = True
       'Set the username textbox to the selected record.
       Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].txtUN = Me.cboUserName.Column(1)
       'Jump to a new record even though the form is filtered.
       Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].SetFocus
       DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
       'Close the previous form - we no longer need it.
       DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_UserName"
```

This will open the `Timesheet - Specialist Entry` from `frm_UserName` form "automatically load [a blank record] when the `Timesheet` form is opened up" using a the selection as the filter.

**2.) Specialist - Timesheet Entry**

Create a new procedure in the Form Open event and add this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_UserName", acNormal, , , , acDialog

End Sub
```

Next, create a new procedure in the Save button `Click` event and add this code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    'Save the record.
    RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    'Load a new record after the save.
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

This will automatically load a blank record when a new record is saved/modified.

I do hope this helps. If you have any questions at all, please let me know. I'd be glad to help even further. I also have a working copy available...

Comment: You know, I'm wondering if we should tell the OP to just ditch his "pop up box" idea. Especially if he/she doesn't know how it works. I see a user name combobox already on the page. Why not use that? We could also make a subform out of the time sheet entry form, and call that with the parameters from the user name combo box.

Comment: I thought the same thing but I stayed as close to the original UI flow as possible - didn't want to completely redesign. They already put a lot of work into it. This also serves as a good learning experience.

Comment: @DanRomano ive added all the above and made some chages. The `form_username` should be called `frm_username` and i believe the reference to `"Username` should be `txtUserName`. If i make those changes and double click the `Specialist - Timesheet Entry` form i get a run time "MS Access cant find the form 'frm_username'. And when i try to debug, this code is in yellow: ` Forms![Specialist - Timesheet Entry].Filter = "txtUserName = '" & Forms![frm_username].cbousername.Column(1) & "'"`

Comment: Answer updated. Let me know if you run into any errors.

Comment: @DanRomano ive made the updates and once i select a user from the pop up, the main form opens and so does the dialog box asking if i would like to save. Once i click "NO" the i get a run time error 2105 "you cant go to the specified record." This line is highlighted in yellow `   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error. I did make a minor update to frm_UserName though.